# How to send package number (tracking_info) in email?

Tags: email, tracking

I have plugin Furgonetka installed on woocommerce. Package numbers are collected from Furgonetka service and presented in the field 'tracking_info' like:

```
Array
(
    [520000016902796077744528] => Array
        (
            [courierService] => inpostkurier
        )

)
```

In data base it is presented like:
a:1:{s:24:"520000016902796077744528";a:1:{s:14:"courierService";s:12:"inpostkurier";}}

I have add function to functions.php which change status of order when it gets tracking info:

```
function update_order_status_when_shipment_tracking_input( $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ){
    if( $meta_key == 'tracking_info' ){
        error_log('update_order_status_when_shipment_tracking_input');
        $order = wc_get_order( $object_id );
        if( $order ){
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'update_postmeta', 'update_order_status_when_shipment_tracking_input', 10, 4 );
```

It works. I would like also send package number in email (it is for example 520000016902796077744528) but I don't how to retrieve this data from field tracking_info.

This is the plugin "Furgonetka" code snippet

```
/**
     * Render html for metaboxes
     */
    public function render_metabox_for_product_page(): void {
        global $post;
        $this->other_package_link_callback();
        $this->package_information( $post );
    }

    /**
     * Render html for package info
     *
     * @param mixed $post - post data.
     */
    public function package_information( $post ) {
        $this->view->render_packages_tracking_info( $this->render_packages_numbers( $post ) );
    }

    /**
     * Renders link to furgonetka iframe
     *
     * @param mixed $post - post data.
     */
    public function other_package_link( $post ) {
        $this->view->render_package_link(
            get_admin_url( null, 'admin.php?page=' . $this->furgonetka_admin->get_plugin_name() . '&idOrder=' . $post->ID ),
            plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ) . 'admin/img/furgonetka-kurirer.svg'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Adding new columns to orders page
     *
     * @param array $columns - columns array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function extra_order_column( array $columns ): array {
        $columns[ $this->furgonetka_admin->get_plugin_name() ] = __( 'Furgonetka.pl', 'furgonetka' );
        $columns['package_number']                             = __( 'Packages tracking numbers', 'furgonetka' );
        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * Render package number.
     *
     * @param mixed $post - post data.
     *
     * @return string|void
     */
    public function render_packages_numbers( $post ) {
        $package_numbers = $this->model
            ->set_order_id( $post->ID )
            ->get_tracking_info();
        if ( empty( $package_numbers ) ) {
            return;
        }
        return $package_numbers;
    }

    /**
     * Get package numbers
     *
     * @param mixed $post - post data.
     *
     * @return array|void
     */
    public function get_packages_numbers( $post ) {
        $package_numbers = $this->model
            ->set_order_id( $post->ID )
            ->get_tracking_info();
        if ( empty( $package_numbers ) ) {
            return array();
        }
        return $package_numbers;
    }

    /**
     * Adding content to new columns in orders page
     *
     * @param string $column - column name.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function extra_order_column_content( string $column ) {
        global $post;

        switch ( $column ) {
            case $this->furgonetka_admin->get_plugin_name():
                $this->other_package_link( $post );
                break;
            case 'package_number':
                $package_numbers = $this->get_packages_numbers( $post );
                foreach ( $package_numbers as $package_number => $package_data ) {

                    if ( Furgonetka_Admin::get_test_mode() ) {
                        echo '<a style="text-decoration : underline" target="_blank" href="https://test.furgonetka.pl/zlokalizuj/' . esc_html( $package_number ) . '">' . esc_html( $package_number ) . '</a><br>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<a style="text-decoration : underline" target="_blank" href="https://furgonetka.pl/zlokalizuj/' . esc_html( $package_number ) . '">' . esc_html( $package_number ) . '</a><br>';
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to send package number in completed email.

Comment: and will this solution help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316337/parcel-locker-address-in-the-order-summary-and-order-details

Comment: Unfortunately not. That solution shows how to send in e-mails the pickup point of "Paczkomaty inPost" chosen by the client in woocommerce. I need to show package number which is generated in Furgonetka and uploaded to woocommerce.